# How I can get line height for each line on screen from UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have `textView`. And I try to get all lines as `[String]` where one element it's one line from the screen, not from all `textView.text`. Also, I must know the height of each line on my screen. We can get line-height from `textView.font`, but it's common height and if we have attributed string each line can have a different height. How I can get the height for each line from the screen?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: All that I tried doesn't work. I can work with range and text positions. But look like I can't work with lines and their indexes.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  @ВикторСлободян

Comment: It is private project and I can't share code. But I already found solution myself. We can get all info about lines from textView layoutManager delegate - shouldSetLineFragmentRect func. This is look not very good and we have some problems in text view when we try load large text. But it is possible.